# SQL to calculate value of Shares at a particular time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm looking for a way that I can calculate what the value of shares are at a given time.

In the example I need to calculate and report on the redemptions of shares in a given month.

There are 3 tables that I need to look at:

1. Redemptions table that has the Date of the redemption, the number of shares that were redeemed and the type of share.
2. The share type table which has the share type and links the 1st and 3rd tables.
3. The Share price table which has the share type, valuation date, value.

So what I need to do is report on and have calculated based on the number of share redemptions the value of those shares broken down by month.

Does that make sense?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Apologies, I think I should elaborate a little further as there might have been some misunderstandings. This isn't to calculate daily changing stocks and shares, it's more for fund management. What this means is that the share price only changes on a monthly basis and it's also normally a month behind.

The effect of this is that the what the query needs to do, is look at the date of the redemption, work out the date ie month and year. Then look at the share price table and if there's a share price for the given date (this will need to be calculated as it will be a single day ie the price was x on day y) then multiple they number of units by this value. However, if there isn't a share price for the given date then use the last price for that particular share type.

Hopefully this might be a little more clear but if there's any other information I can provide to make this easier then please let me know and I'll supply you with the information.

Regards,

Phil

Comment: I don't understand what the 'share type' table is nor why it is needed.

Comment: @No'am Newman, it'd be needed if the other two tables don't contain values for a particular ShareType, but it still needs to be listed on the report.

Comment: The reason for the other table is because some redemptions will be in January when the share price was one value then in February as the price increases then the price is a different value so it needs to be calculated based on the price that relates to the time when the redemptions were logged if that makes sense

Comment: Apologies, I should have added that the share price is only updated monthly. And also the update is done retrospectively so if the current date is April then there might not be a share price for March yet so it needs to look at the February price until a February price is published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick (note: updated to group by ShareType):

```
SELECT
   ST.ShareType,
   RedemptionMonth = DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month, 0, R.RedemptionDate), 0),
   TotalShareValueRedeemed = Sum(P.SharePrice * R.SharesRedeemed)
FROM
   dbo.Redemption R
   INNER JOIN dbo.ShareType ST
      ON R.ShareTypeID = ST.ShareTypeID
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 P.*
      FROM dbo.SharePrice P
      WHERE
         R.ShareTypeID = P.ShareTypeID
         AND R.RedemptionDate >= P.SharePriceDate
      ORDER BY P.SharePriceDate DESC
   ) P
GROUP BY
   ShareType,
   DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month, 0, R.RedemptionDate), 0)
ORDER BY
   ShareType,
   RedemptionMonth
;
```

[See it working in a Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb721e/3).

This can easily be parameterized by simply adding a WHERE clause with conditions on the `Redemption` table. If you need to show a 0 for share types in months where they had no Redemptions, please let me know and I'll improve my answer--it would help if you would fill out your use case scenario a little bit, and describe exactly what you want to input and what you want to see as output.

Also please note: I'm assuming here that there will always be a price for a share redemption--if a redemption exists that is before any share price for it, that redemption will be excluded.

Comment: That is very nearly there, this is actually a step further and better than what I need if that at all makes sense!! As I'm looking for the value for reporting purposes, what I need is for it to return the redemption cash value on a line by line basis on the redemption table.

Comment: In terms of the business case, we have a fund that invests in property in the UK. Within that fund there are various subscriptions from around the world so we have a GBP, EUR, USD, Master and YEN funds. Each fund has it's own share price as they've been established for different periods of time and have been invested into different properties, as such, they have different share prices.

Comment: As investors place their money into the fund in say January 2007 at say a share price of £1.03 then 5 years later they redeem their shares and the price is £1.90 and they are redeeming 10000 unites (shares) then it needs to calculate the value of that redemption. Now as there's a notice period to redeem the funds then we will get notification in early March that it's being redeemed but the share price for March hasn't been set yet

Comment: (share price is set based on the Net Asset Value of the properties that is assessed each month) so it needs to have the value for reporting purposes based on the latest share price until the share price for that relevant month is announced. Does that answer the use case scenario? Your help is greatly appreciated!!! I'm using the query to get the data so that I can produce a report in SQL Reporting. Thanks, Phil

Comment: Oops... I forgot to group by Share Type when I initially posted. I have done so now. Is that better? If not, please detail in what way my query doesn't provide the required results.

Comment: I think you might have it!!! I'm going to try and put this in with my scenario and I'll let you know!! Thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: Do you need shares to show as 0 for a month even if there were no redemptions for that month?

Comment: SORRY!!! I'm very new to this and I think I've missed out a bit of important information as the results are not coming back correct I don't think. In the redemption table, what actually happens is that the same data is loaded many times. The reason for this is every day, we receive information on share transactions. These sheets are then just uploaded so if we get notification on the 1st of the month, that transaction will be imported many times so we need to only look at the most recent import for that period. There is a field in the redemption table called "Period No_".

Comment: You're going to have to provide more detail. Modify your question. Use my fiddle--rewrite it until it looks like your data. Show a sample desired result. Then, and only then, can I help you without wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the valuations for every day, then the calculation is a simple join followed by an aggregation.  The resulting query is something like:

```
select year(redemptiondate), month(redemptiondate),
       sum(r.NumShares*sp.Price) as TotalPrice
from Redemptions r left outer join
     ShareType st
     on r.sharetype = st.sharetype left outer join
     SharePrice sp
     on st.sharename = sp.sharename and r.redemptiondate = sp.pricedate
group by year(redemptiondate), month(redemptiondate)
order by 1, 2;
```

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have a daily valuation, it's monthly and ta make it a bit more complicated it's normally a month behind so we would also need for it to take into account the most recent and to use this is there was a price for the month in question.

Comment: @Pipster1981: you should add this information about having only one value per month to your question because it is very relevant to the answer. It's also totally inaccurate - a stock's price could change by 10% during a month.

Comment: I know a traditional stocks price could, however, this isn't a traditional stock price, this is a share price and a share price for a fund can be updated monthly as this is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you need a query like

```
select shares.id, shares.name, sum (redemption.quant * shareprices.price)
from shares 
inner join redemption on shares.id = redemption.share
inner join shareprices on shares.id = shareprices.share
where redemption.curdate between :p1 and :p2
order by shares.id
group by shares.id, shares.name
```

:p1 and :p2 are date parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you just need it for one date range:

```
SELECT s.ShareType, SUM(ISNULL(sp.SharePrice, 0) * ISNULL(r.NumRedemptions, 0)) [RedemptionPrice]
FROM dbo.Shares s   
LEFT JOIN dbo.Redemptions r
    ON r.ShareType = s.ShareType
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 SharePrice
    FROM dbo.SharePrice p
    WHERE p.ShareType = s.ShareType
    AND p.ValuationDate <= r.RedemptionDate
    ORDER BY p.ValuationDate DESC) sp
WHERE r.RedemptionDate BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2
GROUP BY s.ShareType
```

Where @Date1 and @Date2 are your dates

The `ISNULL` checks are just there so it actually gives you a value if something is null (it'll be 0). It's completely optional in this case, just a personal preference.

The `OUTER APPLY` acts like a `LEFT JOIN` that will filter down the results from SharePrice to make sure you get the most recent ValuationDate from table based on the RedemptionDate, even if it wasn't from the same date range as that date. It could probably be achieved another way, but I feel like this is easily readable.

If you don't feel comfortable with the OUTER APPLY, you could use a subquery in the SELECT part (i.e., `ISNULL(r.NumRedemptions, 0) * (/* subquery from dbo.SharePrice here */)`

Comment: Maybe go with r.RedemptionDate rather than @Date2 in the subquery to get the closest price

Comment: @Blam Good call, I'll make the edit. I don't think that can be filtered out in a subquery in the join though, it'll have to move somewhere else.

Comment: The APPLY operator is similar to the JOIN operator, but the difference is that the right-hand side operator of APPLY can reference columns from the left-hand side.

Comment: Yep, that's the route I decided on.